# How to retrieve element's ID's name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 <div class="slider">
        <li id="hello1"></li>
        <li id="hello2"></li>
        <li id="hello3"></li>
  </div>
```

I did this approach in JavaScript. I am wondering how to do it in jQuery.

```
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++ ) {
    console.log(li[i].id);
}
```

Comment: Everyone is recommending `.attr()` to get an element's ID. Don't do it.  Just because a jQuery method *can* be used, doesn't mean it should. Just use the `.id` property. Shorter and faster.

Comment: I am trying to learn jQuery.Thanks for your advise tho.

Comment: Just saying that part of using jQuery is knowing when to *not* use it. But to find basic functionality, read its docs: http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 2):

Here is more of a JQuery way to do this

```
$('.slider li').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

### [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/pjn6xqmd/1/)

Comment: Why not `$('.slider li')` :)

Comment: totally agreed @SteveRobbins

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var li = $('.slider li');

li.each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
})
```

Using Jquery element selector this is very easy( `$('element')` ). And the returned object can be iterated using `.each()`.

**Update** : As @squint suggested, you can simply use :

```
console.log(this.id);
```

[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/75e4w2vs/2/)

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you could do:

```
var li = $("li"),
    i;
for(i = 0; i < li.length; i++){
  console.log($(li[i]).attr('id'));
}
```